# CakePhp 4.x basic Authentication

Tags: cakephp

I am following the CakePHP 4.x tutorial to the letter (as far as I can see) until chapter "CMS Tutorial - Authentication".

Half way through "Now, on every request, the AuthenticationMiddleware will inspect the request session to look for an authenticated user. If we are loading the /users/login page, it will also inspect the posted form data (if any) to extract the credentials."

When I try to access articles or users I get an error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Interface
> 'Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface' not found in
> C:\wamp64\www\cake\src\Application.php on line 41

I have tried to figure out why this would be, but I cannot find it. I have tried looking up the same problem on the internet, no dice. Not even a mention that this could be security related (I found a mention about strict brower settings earlier but it was related to another problem).

I have uploaded my code on Github here: https://github.com/plafeber/cakephp-tutorial

I would greatly appreciate any feedback. I was under the assumption that if I create the full code set from the tutorial, given of course I run CakePHP 4.1.5 and follow the related Cake 4.x manual, that it would work. However, I already found out that I have to change the line about the use of DefaultPasswordHasher compared to what was in the code. So I can imagine the Tutorial page is not exactly as it should be.

This would be hte correct line about the use of the DefaultPasswordHasher in User.php;

```
//the use line
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher as AuthDefaultPasswordHasher;

//and the function
    protected function _setPassword(string $password) : ?string
    {
        if (strlen($password) > 0) {
             $hasher = new AuthDefaultPasswordHasher();
             return $hasher->hash($password);
        }
    }
```

Comment: read: book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html

Comment: Please do not post your code externally, especially not as ZIP files that need to be downloaded and extracted, questions on SO should be self-contained, so that they don't easily become outdated and incomprehensible. Please update your question with information on how exactly you've installed the authentication plugin, the error message suggests that you didn't do that, or didn't do it correctly. btw, the CMS tutorial is correct, you're supposed to use the hasher from the authentication plugin, not the one from the core, which was introduced for the deprecated auth component.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The tutorial explains that you install the plugin by entering on the command line;
composer require cakephp/authentication:^2.0
That's what I did. It installed without any errors. I have found the related files in vendor\cakephp\authentication (at least I think those are the related files).

Comment: I think the problem may indeed have been around installation and specifically the location from where one runs the Composer call. I noticed that there was a  \vendor folder next to the cake install directory. Looking back, I have run the Composer call from the webroot, not the cake install dir. I have now run the call again from the cake install dir and now I get no error message. I have an issue with redirect, but that basically tells me it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to navigate to the Cake install dir (containing the src and config folder and so on), then running the Composer call again. This apparently placed the filed in the right directories and then the error no longer appeared.